# String with different characters

Tags: python

Could you please tell what is wrong with my code? I am trying to solve the following problem:
"Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters."

Example:

Input: `s = "abcabcbb"`

Output: 3

Explanation: The answer is `"abc"`, with the length of 3.

My code is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        count=[0]*len(s);
        for i in range(0,len(s)):
            for j in range(1,len(s)-i):
                if s[i]!=s[i+j]:
                    count[i]=count[i]+1;
                else:
                    break;
        return max(count);
```

It returns 4, although the answer is 3.

Comment: When you compare `s[0]` with `s[4]` they're not equal, so you increment `count[0]`. But there's a repeated `a` between them, so they're not part of the same substring and shouldn't be counted.

Answer (score 2):

here you go, start at 1 because every letter is technically a unique string of len 1, and each loop checks if the next letter in in the slice currently looked at

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: str) -> int:

    if s=='': return 0

    count=[1]*len(s)
    for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
            if s[j] in s[i:j]:
                break
            count[i]+=1
    return max(count)
```

Comment: good point, always handle edge cases